# Listview , open new activity onClick

Tags: android, listview

Hey everyone I've looked for hours trying to find a solution to this, my goal is to have a Listview when it opens well open another activity. Well actually I got it to be able to open another activity when its click but how do I get it so that each list item will open its own activity? I am terribly sorry if this question is already answered but the links I found doesn't really describe what the code is doing [Yes i am a newbie :)]

this is the code im using

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.newfile, countries));

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Html_file.class);
             startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        if(position == 1) {
            //code specific to first list item    
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Html_file1.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

        if(position == 2) {
            //code specific to 2nd list item    
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Html_file2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
  int position, long id) {
   switch( position ) {
     case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i1.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
              break;
     case 1:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i2.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
              break;
     case 2:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i3.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
              break;
     case 3:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i4.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
              break;
     case 4:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i5.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
              break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have some limited number of list you can use switch case here on position

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Html_file.class);
             startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know which activity is to be opened when different list items are clicked, then just assign id or tag to the list items.
In the callback of onItemClick, you have a parameter View,
use it to get id or tag to differentiate them and call respective Activity.

Comment: thank you for providing an answer for a more complicated problem.

Answer (score 0):

// Add ArrayList and ArrayAdapter:

```
    final ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        listItems.add("image_one");
        listItems.add("image_two");
        listItems.add("image_three");

    ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
```

// Add **ArrayList of Classes**:

```
    final ArrayList<Class> intents = new ArrayList<Class>();
        intents.add(image_one.class);
        intents.add(image_two.class);
        intents.add(image_three.class);
```

// Click on list item to open Class from **ArrayList of Classes**:

```
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position, long id) {

            Intent listIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
            intents.get(position)); 
            startActivity(listIntent);
        }
    });
```

[SEE IMAGE OF CLASS NAMES HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZmWJ.png)