# how to run an another class activity after toast message displayed?

Tags: android, onclick

```
    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
             String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tcpSocket.SendMessage(FramePacket.FramesendMessageCmd(item));


        }
    });
```

herer is my code. i want to start another activity after click on the message item.
i tried a lot. But not working. any one know help me please. how to solve this. I tried a lot. it give nullpointer exception error.

catlog error here

```
 09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dispatchsystem/com.dispatchsystem.JobStartedScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
 09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
 09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
 09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at com.dispatchsystem.JobStartedScreen.onCreate(JobStartedScreen.java:65)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-02 13:36:44.364: E/AndroidRuntime(28601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
```

jobstartedscreen

```
 public class JobStartedScreen extends Activity  implements OnMessageReceived{

TextView tv_JobNo;
static TextView tv_JobKm;
static TextView tv_JobwaitngTime;
TextView tvjobstartedtime;
Button btn_jobFinsh;
Button btn_msg;
boolean _ThreadFlag=false;
boolean _ResumeThread=false;
private Window w;
Thread t=null;
String tag="Jobstartscreen";
private static MyThread sThread;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     setContentView(R.layout.jobstartedscreen);
    if (savedInstanceState==null){
        Contsants.VehicleStartOdometer=0.0F;
        sThread=new MyThread(mHandler);
        sThread.start();
    }
    StateManager.DeviceStatus=StateManager.hired;
    tcpSocket.setmMessageListener(this);
    tv_JobNo =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvJobid);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    tv_JobNo.setText(bundle.get("Jobno").toString());

    tv_JobKm =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvjobKm);
    tv_JobwaitngTime =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvjobWaittime);

    tv_JobwaitngTime.setText("Waiting Time : 0:0");
    //update the Km every 1 sec
    Log.d(tag, "On created "+_ResumeThread);
    tvjobstartedtime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_jobStarttime);
    tvjobstartedtime.setText("Start Time :"+Contsants.jobStartTime);

    btn_jobFinsh= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_jobFinsh);
    btn_jobFinsh.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    btn_msg= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_msg);
    btn_msg.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

}
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    w = this.getWindow();
    w.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    w.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    w.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    Log.d("job start on resume",_ThreadFlag+" "+_ResumeThread);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (sThread.isAlive()){
        sThread.setHandler(mHandler);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if (sThread.isAlive()){
        sThread.setHandler(null);
    }
}

boolean _Paused=false;
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    _Paused=true;
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
}

private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_jobFinsh:
            //DO something
            _ThreadFlag=true;
            StateManager.JobStatus=StateManager.jobstatus_dropped;
            tcpSocket.SendMessage(FramePacket.FrameJobStatusCmd(Contsants.Jobno,StateManager.JobStatus) );
             SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");
             String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
             Contsants.jobEndTime=currentDateandTime;
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),JobCompletionScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);
            sThread.setHandler(null);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_msg:
            /*Intent iNAV = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=12.920629,77.610643&daddr=12.990346, 77.589521")
                    );
            startActivity(iNAV);*/
            Intent imsg = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MessageList.class);
            startActivity(imsg);
            break;

        }
    }
};

static Handler mHandler =new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message){
        //update UI
        Bundle b = message.getData();
        float odometer = b.getFloat("My Odometer");
        int waiting =b.getInt("waiting Time");
        tv_JobKm.setText(odometer+" Km");
        tv_JobwaitngTime.setText("Waiting Time : "+Integer.toString((waiting / 60)) +":"+ Integer.toString((waiting% 60)));
    }
};

private class MyThread extends Thread{
    private Handler mHandler;

    public MyThread(Handler handler){
        super();
        mHandler=handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //some long operation
        if (mHandler!=null)
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        _ResumeThread=true;
        while(!_ThreadFlag)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);   
                Message msg = new Message();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putFloat("My Odometer", (float) (gpsdataElements.Distance-Contsants.jobStartKm));
                if(gpsdataElements.Speed==0.0)
                {
                    Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec++;
                }
                b.putInt("waiting Time",  Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec);
                //  tv_JobwaitngTime.setText("Waiting Time : "+Integer.toString((Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec / 60)) +":"+ Integer.toString((Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec % 60)));
                //send message to the handler with the current message handler          
                msg.setData(b);
                // send message to the handler with the current message handler
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("Error", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler handler){
        mHandler=handler;
    }
}

@Override
public void messageReceived(String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Job StartScreem : Recived data :"+message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}

 }
```

Comment: See [Listview , open new activity onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660126/listview-open-new-activity-onclick)

Comment: You want to change activity on listItem click or on toast message click, i didn't get it.

Comment: that one is ok dude.But i want to start an another activity when click on any message item. how can i do that. for this i want to write loop condtion?

Comment: @Jilbertalistitem click dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use Handler in side onClick

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
             String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tcpSocket.SendMessage(FramePacket.FramesendMessageCmd(item));
          new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MyAct.this.startActivity(new Intent(MyAct.this,Abc.class));

                }
            }, 5000);

        }
    });
```

public void run()
{
instert you next activity here

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code as:

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
         String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         Intent intent= new Intent(youractivitycontext, AnotherActivity.class); 
         startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

this will take you to another activity, specified by your **AnotherActivity.class**. You may also pass data to your next activity, as it seems that you are trying to do so. and there are several ways for that. go [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to understand Intents

Comment: in my code i have more than 10 class. if i click means it moves to all other activities except jobstartedscreen.class. I don't know where was the error was.

Comment: @user2738655 What is the error about? can you show your logcat? It must be due to something other than this Intent stuff. let's check it out. Show logcoat.

Comment: @user2738655 Dude, according to your logcat, there's a nullpointer exception in your **onCreate** method of your **jobstartedscreen** activity. but according to your provided code for **jobstartedscreen** activity, your line number 65 lies outside of your **onCreate** method. are you sure, is it the updated code? executing which, gives the provided logcat?

Answer (score 0):

After showing your toast do.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(youractivitycontext, AnotherActivity.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i posted. I want to move jobstartedscreen.class when click on the any of the list item.

Comment: What is there in line no 65 of jobstartedscreen.Java

Comment: are you sending any extra information through the intent. I guess when you are firing the intent before that you are not setting any extra values . thats why it may get a null pointer when you are doing    `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    tv_JobNo.setText(bundle.get("Jobno").toString());`

Comment: if you are not sending then in that case you may do the following ::
`Intent intent= new Intent(Your_present_Activity.this, JobStartedScreen.class);
intent.putExtra("JobNo",jobNo.tostring());
startActivity(intent);`and in oncreate of JobStartedScreen do
`if(getIntent.hasExtra("JobNo")){
tv_JobNo.setText(getIntent.getExtra("JobNo"));`

Comment: From the logcat its visible that you are navigating to JobStartedScreen activity but somehow getting a NPE in oncreate of that activity line no 65. From the code you posted i could only the figure the place where the NPE can Occur is `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();tv_JobNo.setText(bundle.get("Jobno").toString());` this. bundle.get("Jobno") might be giving null as you might not have passed the additional parameter(job no) to your JobStartedScreen activity. It can be passed how I have mentioned in the previous mentioned comment. Hope this is the problem.