# How open new activity clicking an item in listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, onclicklistener, package-managers

I can't start a new activity clicking over an item in my listview. I want that `onItemClick` can open the `ApkInfoActivity`.. Actually when i click nothing happen.

```
protected void onItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id, AdapterView<?> parent) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

       final ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);

       PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

       AppDataActivity appData = (AppDataActivity) getApplicationContext();
       appData.setPackageInfo(packageInfo);

       Intent appInfo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApkInfoActivity.class);
       startActivity(appInfo);

    }
```

I can't find the problem..How can i solve?

EDIT with logcat:

```
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo cannot be cast to android.content.pm.PackageInfo
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at com.dd.application.MainActivity.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:369)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:297)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1149)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2939)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at android.widget.AbsListView$2.run(AbsListView.java:3622)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:743)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559)
10-29 17:14:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(3535):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `Intent appInfo = new Intent(ActivityName.this, ApkInfoActivity.class);
       startActivity(appInfo)` this is sufficient unless you want to pass some values to `ApkInfoActivity`

Comment: Are you calling in this way listView.onItemClickListener  ?

Comment: also do your list items have buttons so they take focus instead

Comment: I'm not using `listView.onItemClickListener` actually.. have i to do it?

Comment: @Raghunandan the list doesn't have buttons..

Comment: @David_D you need `listView.setOnItemClickListener(this)` this refers to activity context and your activity should implements `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: @David_D post your class code where you have the list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listview , open new activity onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660126/listview-open-new-activity-onclick)

Answer (score 19):

Use This for doing your work

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
      Intent appInfo = new Intent(YourActivity.this, ApkInfoActivity.class);
       startActivity(appInfo);
   } 
});
```

Comment: I have an error here: `new AdapterView.onItemClickListener()`.. the error is: AdapterView.onItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 11):

```
public class MenuYangu extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = { "Quiz Trivia", "Sign A New User", "Friend List",
"Download A File", "Upload A File", "Select Pdf files", "Memory Game",
"Dzidza Maths", "Write Exam" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menuone.this,
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

if (position == 0) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
else if (position == 1) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
 else if (position == 2) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, FriendList.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 } 
 }

 }

 }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: For example , if you want to open first view i.e Quiz Trivia which is at position 0 , it will open the desire class you enter. sorry my english is weak. hope you understood.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Intent, You can also pass the clicked listview item data to your new activity.

```
String classes[] = { "Quiz Trivia", "Sign A New User", "Friend List",
"Download A File", "Upload A File", "Select Pdf files", "Memory Game",
"Dzidza Maths", "Write Exam" };

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {                   
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ApkInfoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",classes[i]);
                startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

}
```

Output:

[image: ListView Open Another Activity OnItemClick]

You can find the whole tutorial [here](https://larntech.com/android-custom-listview-that-open-new-activity-to-display-clicked-item/)

Answer (score 0):

Add setOnItemclickListener() for your Listview.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`Intent appInfo = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ApkInfoActivity.class);
       startActivity(appInfo);`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the visibility from `protected` to `public` for your method header.

**Edit**

Now that I look at it, your method header is actually wrong.  It should be the following:

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

The variables must be in the same order as they are in the Interface they implement.

Comment: Have i also Override the method?

Answer (score 0):

for instance if u want to open an activity based on the text u click in listview,ie if "abcd" is the option clicked on the listview and u want to open the activity with the very same name "abcd",then perform this ..

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    String temp=yourarray[position];


    try{
        Class myclass=Class.forName("yourpackagename."+temp);
        Intent in=new Intent(this,myclass);
        startActivity(in);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving an explanation to my answer. I assume that you have set your listview in order just as in your posted code. I will only review this part of your code:
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
I don't this is necessary.
In the case of the example I gave:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
      if(position==0){
     Intent appInfo = new Intent(SwahiliService.this, DisplayActivity.class);
      startActivity(appInfo);
  } 
      if(position==1){
          Intent english=new Intent(SwahiliService.this,EnglishService.class);
          startActivity(english);
      }
      if(position==2){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You have selected pst3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

I am just setting a lister to my listview which I have called lv,
my adapter(which is the holder of my listview items) sets three variables, a View, int for position and long for argument:,
I refer to the item selected on listview by its position which as usual starts at 0 (though you can instantiate it to start at any other number as you wish e,g int position=1, starts the item count at 1).
From here you can then use any control struct to start activity as per item clicked, in my case, I used a for loop since I assumed my listview has three items only, for larger listview items, you can use a for-loop.
Please note how I start my new activity by first referencing to current activity as follows (SwahiliService.this) of which can safely be replace by (this keyword only) and then follows the activity I want to start.
I hope this is now more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

// Add ArrayList and ArrayAdapter:

```
    final ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        listItems.add("image_one");
        listItems.add("image_two");
        listItems.add("image_three");

    ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
```

// Add **ArrayList of Classes**:

```
    final ArrayList<Class> intents = new ArrayList<Class>();
        intents.add(image_one.class);
        intents.add(image_two.class);
        intents.add(image_three.class);
```

// Click on list item to open Class from **ArrayList of Classes**:

```
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position, long id) {

            Intent listIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
            intents.get(position)); 
            startActivity(listIntent);
        }
    });
```

[SEE IMAGE OF CLASS NAMES HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZmWJ.png)

Comment: Please post the code  and not an image of the code.

Comment: Sorry, there it is

Answer (score -1):

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
          if(position==0){
         Intent appInfo = new Intent(SwahiliService.this, DisplayActivity.class);
          startActivity(appInfo);
      } 
          if(position==1){
              Intent english=new Intent(SwahiliService.this,EnglishService.class);
              startActivity(english);
          }
          if(position==2){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You have selected pst3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
   }});
```

Comment: Please provide explanation of how your code fixes the issue for OP.