# how to go to new activity after clicking an item in the listview?

Tags: java, android

this is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    String HTTP_JSON_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/positivity/all_subjects.php";

    EditText editText;

    List SubjectArrayList = new ArrayList();

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

        // Calling Method to Parese JSON data into listView.
        new GetHttpResponse(MainActivity.this).execute();

        // Calling EditText addTextChangedListener method which controls the EditText type sequence.
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                //Updating Array Adapter ListView after typing inside EditText.
                MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        // Adding On item click listener on ListView.
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String Item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                // Showing ListView click item using Toast message on screen.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    // Creating GetHttpResponse message to parse JSON.

    public class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        // Creating context.
        public Context context;

        // Creating string to hold Http response result.
        String ResultHolder;

        // Creating constructor .
        public GetHttpResponse(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Sending the Http URL into HttpServicesClass to parse JSON.
            HttpServicesClass httpServiceObject = new HttpServicesClass(HTTP_JSON_URL);
            try {
                httpServiceObject.ExecutePostRequest();

                // If the server response code = 200 then JSON parsing start.
                if (httpServiceObject.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    // Adding Http response into ResultHolder string.
                    ResultHolder = httpServiceObject.getResponse();

                    // If there is response present into ResultHolder.
                    if (ResultHolder != null) {
                        // Creating JSONArray and set it to null.
                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                        try {

                            // Adding ResultHolder into JSONArray.
                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(ResultHolder);

                            // Creating JSONObject.
                            JSONObject jsonObject;

                            // Starting for loop at the end of jsonArray length.
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                // Adding JSON array object .
                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Adding the JSON parse object into SubjectArrayList.
                                SubjectArrayList.add(jsonObject.getString("subject_Name").toString());

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // If something goes wrong then showing the error message on screen.
                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServiceObject.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        // This block will execute after done all background processing.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Hiding the progress bar after done loading JSON.
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Showing the ListView after done loading JSON.
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Setting up the SubjectArrayList into Array Adapter.
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, SubjectArrayList);


            // Passing the Array Adapter into ListView.
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How open new activity clicking an item in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662233/how-open-new-activity-clicking-an-item-in-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity, where you defined your listview

you write

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    String HTTP_JSON_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/positivity/all_subjects.php";

    EditText editText;

    List SubjectArrayList = new ArrayList();

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

        // Calling Method to Parese JSON data into listView.
        new GetHttpResponse(MainActivity.this).execute();

        // Calling EditText addTextChangedListener method which controls the EditText type sequence.
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                //Updating Array Adapter ListView after typing inside EditText.
                MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        // Adding On item click listener on ListView.
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//ItemClicked item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
   if(position==0)
          {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,one.class);
            //based on item add info to intent
            startActivity(intent);
           }
            }
        });
    }

    // Creating GetHttpResponse message to parse JSON.

    public class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        // Creating context.
        public Context context;

        // Creating string to hold Http response result.
        String ResultHolder;

        // Creating constructor .
        public GetHttpResponse(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Sending the Http URL into HttpServicesClass to parse JSON.
            HttpServicesClass httpServiceObject = new HttpServicesClass(HTTP_JSON_URL);
            try {
                httpServiceObject.ExecutePostRequest();

                // If the server response code = 200 then JSON parsing start.
                if (httpServiceObject.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    // Adding Http response into ResultHolder string.
                    ResultHolder = httpServiceObject.getResponse();

                    // If there is response present into ResultHolder.
                    if (ResultHolder != null) {
                        // Creating JSONArray and set it to null.
                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                        try {

                            // Adding ResultHolder into JSONArray.
                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(ResultHolder);

                            // Creating JSONObject.
                            JSONObject jsonObject;

                            // Starting for loop at the end of jsonArray length.
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                // Adding JSON array object .
                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Adding the JSON parse object into SubjectArrayList.
                                SubjectArrayList.add(jsonObject.getString("subject_Name").toString());

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // If something goes wrong then showing the error message on screen.
                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServiceObject.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        // This block will execute after done all background processing.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Hiding the progress bar after done loading JSON.
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Showing the ListView after done loading JSON.
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Setting up the SubjectArrayList into Array Adapter.
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, SubjectArrayList);


            // Passing the Array Adapter into ListView.
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but i am a newbie can you be more specific about this code:

Comment: ok, i can add this code into yours. But you need to tell me what activity you want to open with intent. The name of it

Comment: well the activity name is one

Comment: ok, I added the listener to your code in edited answer; copy it and let me know if it worked

Comment: Error:(84, 17) error: cannot find symbol class ItemClicked this is the error i am getting

Comment: just delete this line it accidentally got here from my app, it won;t affect your code, and make sure your class name is spelled one.class

Comment: the same error app stops working when i click any item in the listview

Comment: is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: does it still show the error? can you please post line 84 where it occurs, as it is not in the listener as I checked it to the studio

Comment: yup still getting the same error this is the line 84:                       
  ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: but DELETE this line! it's not supposed to be there)) It accidentally got there from my project. You said you deleted it....

Comment: sorry yea i deleted that line but still the same problem continues

Comment: on what line? It cannot be the same as the previous error stated it couldn't find ItemClicked class(but we got rid of it)

Comment: i am not getting any error after the changes but when i am trying to click that item in emulator the app stops working

Comment: when I loaded your code to the studio it showed another error in initialization of adapter you should specify the type you'll send to adapter . For example ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayAdapter; the same is with ArrayList. 

1. Google how to initialize ArrayAdapter and ArrayList. 2. Check the names of activities in intent if they correspond in case to the actual names (one.class or One.class???)

Comment: thank you for your support the issue has been resolved

Comment: Glad to hear that, if you got it working with the help of my answer then could you kindly mark the  answer as accepted ( just hit the tick sign to the left of the answer) and i'm going edit to clean it out a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try this one example, actually its same as anywhere else

```
    mListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Intent intentToYoklamaAl = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
         //   intentToYoklamaAl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intentToYoklamaAl);
           // overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
          //  finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you explain what is  fade_in and fade_out

Comment: My bad. You can ignore it, its just a transition effect while passing to new activity. You may pass this in this sittuation but its a good feature to learn.