# Listview opening activity after a Toast

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

How can i make clicking a item on a listview open a another activity. For example, if i click France it should display the toast and open my france.java activity. This is just for testing and experience as im still learning how to properly layout or? format code.

```
public class weapons extends Activity {
  ListView list;
  String[] web = {
      "Brazil",
      "France",
      "Japan",
      "USA",
      "Russia"
  } ;
  Integer[] imageId = {
      R.drawable.brazil,
      R.drawable.france,
      R.drawable.japan,
      R.drawable.usa,
      R.drawable.russia,
  };
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.weapons);
    CustomList adapter = new
        CustomList(weapons.this, web, imageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list22);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(weapons.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            });
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what's problem ? use intent to start activity,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listview , open new activity onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660126/listview-open-new-activity-onclick)

Comment: This is not a question for SO. My grandma can find an answer at google or SO in a minute, do you can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
String clicked=(String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
switch(clicked){
case "Brazil":
Toast.makeText(weapons.this, "You Clicked at "+clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Brazil.class);
startActivity(intent);
break;
case "France":
Toast.makeText(weapons.this, "You Clicked at "+clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, France.class);
startActivity(intent);
default:
break;}
                    }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent to start Activity
Use following code in onItemClick

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the new activity in `onItemClick`

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(weapons.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(weapons.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

```
   mlistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                  // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text Game, Help, Home
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);

              });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code :**

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {

        TextView tv = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        String str = tv.getText().toString().trim();

        if (str.equals(web[0])) {
            Intent int0 = new Intent(weapons.this, Brazil.class);
            startActivity(int0);
        }else if(str.equals(web[1])) {
            Intent int1 = new Intent(weapons.this, France.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        }else if(str.equals(web[2])) {
            Intent int2 = new Intent(weapons.this, Japan.class);
            startActivity(int2);
        }else if(str.equals(web[3])) {
            Intent int3 = new Intent(weapons.this, USA.class);
            startActivity(int3);
        }else if(str.equals(web[4])) {
            Intent int1 = new Intent(weapons.this, Russia.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User this code

```
Toast.makeText(this, "your message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

(new Handler())
    .postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
    }
    }, timeInMillisecondTheToastIsShowingFor);
```